# Advantages of knowing foreign languages for natural language processing

Tags: natural-language-processing

I wonder about cases in which knowing several languages can lead a researcher to  interesting results in natural language processing.

For example, knowledge of foreign languages can without doubt contribute to better machine translation, it's the most obvious example.

In what other fields of NLP can a researcher benefit from knowing several languages?

Comment: At my university all Computational Linguists need to learn several languages to a basic competency level. It helps with understanding grammar, phonetics etc. It's also useful to learn a language like Japanese where a lot of meaning is left implicit and the listener is expected to deduce a lot from context.

Comment: In all languages "a lot of meaning is left implicit and the listener is expected to deduce a lot from context". Your own language, for example. It does make sense, though, to learn languages from different language families, especially ones that are typologically different.